# snmpwalk Unknown Object Identifier

Tags: snmp

I have a device with snmp configured and gives lots of result for

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1
```

but when i querry a particular section like system or interface it fails as below .... Is there a way to check what all sections are present in the MIB or may be printing whole tree.

```
xyz@xyz-VirtualBox:~$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 udp
udp: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> udp)
xyz@xyz-VirtualBox:~$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 cmot
cmot: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> cmot)
xyz@xyz-VirtualBox:~$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 system
system: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> system)
xyz@xyz-VirtualBox:~$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 interfaces
interfaces: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> interfaces)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmot: Unknown Object Identifier` shows you that `cmot` isn't found in known MIBs.

You need add device's MIBs to snmp client via `cp MY-MIB.txt /usr/share/snmp/mibs` or use snmp client without MIB.

By example to get system info:

`snmpwalk -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1`

Or you can tell the tools to load MY-MIB file for this command only:

`snmpwalk -m +MY-MIB -v2c -c public 1.1.1.1 cmot`